gdal.Translate producing error
I'm running a Python script that uses gdal.Translate to set an area of interest. I believe that the important parts are:
from osgeo import gdal, osr, ogr
# ...
translate_options = gdal.TranslateOptions(projWin = [extent[0], extent[3], extent[2], extent[1]],  width = sizex, height = sizey)
gdal.Translate(dir + date_file + '_mosaic.tif', dir + date_file +'_mosaic.vrt', options=translate_options)

And the error generated is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 157, in <module>
    gdal.Translate(dir + date_file + '_mosaic.tif', dir + date_file +'_mosaic.vrt', options=translate_options)
  File "Miniconda3/envs/showcast/lib/python3.12/site-packages/osgeo/gdal.py", line 823, in Translate
    return TranslateInternal(destName, srcDS, opts, callback, callback_data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "Miniconda3/envs/showcast/lib/python3.12/site-packages/osgeo/gdal.py", line 6102, in TranslateInternal
    return _gdal.TranslateInternal(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: Received a NULL pointer.

I believe this error is related to some environment problem, because other people elsewhere are using this script, apparently with no problems. The machine I'm using is an old CentOS 6.9 Linux that cannot be upgraded because it uses some proprietary software. Python environment is controlled by an installation of Miniconda. Gdal version is 3.8.5.
So I tried to run the script on a different machine. On this other machine I did not install Miniconda, I just ran the script using python libraries installed from the regular package management system. Gdal is also 3.8.5 and the script runs ok.
I guess some other package, or perhaps Python itself needs to change version on the machine where the script doesn't work. Any ideas on how to proceed, which other libraries to check?

Maybe GDAL can not read the input dataset. Put gdal.UseExceptions() and print(gdal.Info("dir + date_file +'_mosaic.vrt'")) before the call to gdal.Translate to see if any errors are raised that provide more info.

What is the value of dir? Does dir + date_file +'_mosaic.vrt' actually exist or are you mising a '', perhaps you want os.path.join(dir, date_file +'_mosaic.vrt') to ensure the appropriate path seperator is inserted.

Following directions from user2856 and Michael Stimson, I found out that the data directory in use had no write permission for the running user, thus producing the error.
Calling gdal.UseExceptions() did produce a better error message.
